# Replace current fragment after activity starts

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

how can I start new activity and close current fragment synchronously.

I have delay between replacing current fragment and starting new activity.

Replacing fragment works immediately, but for activity I have to wait about 200ms. It's looks ugly.

```
@Override
public void onCategoryChoosen(int id) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, GameActivity.class));

    openStartFragment();
}

private void openStartFragment() {
    setZeroMargin();
    StartFragment startFragment = new StartFragment().newInstance();
    ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentSlide(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            startFragment, mFrameContainer);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to replace something that is directly afterwards hidden by a activity?

Comment: MainActivity -> start fragment -> choose opponent -> choose category
GameActivity -> question fragment n

Comment: why dont u try to put your choose category inside another fragment and avoid putting code in another activity? Then when you need to go to a very differenciated controller you can  transition to GameActivity where you may start the game with the parameters from the fragments embed on the MainActivity